# Is there a way to add checkbox in a microsoft bot cards?

Tags: botframework

I've a carousel with cards. Where the user can choose one card and he then can ask about that particular card details.

[image]

When I look into the metadata of thumbnail

```
public ThumbnailCard(string title = null, string subtitle = null, string text = null, IList<CardImage> images = null, IList<CardAction> buttons = null, CardAction tap = null);
```

we can only see buttons.

Comment: No, there's no facility for that yet, and I doubt there ever will be - it wouldn't play nicely on the channels.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do that and I'm fully sure that most of the current channels  doesn't support checkboxes. If you are using the WebChat channel, you might be able to build something custom and add that feature since the code it's [open source.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Comment: Multiple cards selection should be a default functionality. I'm really disappointed :(